# Не могу зайти на сайты майкрософт со своего IP

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10

**Проблема:** мне нужно было обновить Visual studio installer и установить пару вещей, но обновление так и не происходило, оно просто вырубалось, я пробовал переустановить сам инсталлер, но столкнулся с проблемой что не могу зайти на сайт майкрософта, попробовал через VPN и все вышло, скачал, начал устанавливать обновление, и тут снова, нет соединения, я нашел выход в том, что бы использовать десктопный vpn, но минус в том, что нужно скачать около 5гб данных, а впн-ы в основном платные, или ограниченные, и качать кучу разных триал/демо версий не очень круто.

**Предположение:** возможно я не прав и несу чушь, судя по всему домены майкрософта заблочены для моего IP, ибо в независимости от сети, времени суток, и.т.п. такой трабл только на моем ноуте.

**Попытка решить:** я пытался в файле hosts посмотреть и найти заблокированые домены, нет не то, смотрел в брандмауэре, тож ничего не нашел (мб плохо искал, но в упор не нашел)

Comment: Тебе выслать архив 2019й версии?

Comment: Стоп. На ноуте? А на компе или на ноуте друга\виртуалке, но в твоей квартире - всё ок?

Comment: Mss в mtu не пролезает? С гуглом и ютубом проблем нет?

Comment: @eri нет, с этим проблем нет, гугл и ютуб в порядке

Comment: @donRumata Да, как и написал, только с моим ноутом траблы, в независимости от сети, я пробовал и дома, и в универе, и в кафешке, в виртуалке не пробовал, но думаю это нового ничего не даст

Comment: И под свежесозданным юзером на этом ноуте тоже не хочет качать?

Comment: `в виртуалке не пробовал, но думаю это нового ничего не даст`. А вот это ты зря. Потому что настройки твоей системы\профиля - не то же самое, что и сетевой мост\нат в виртуалке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В решении проблемы помог простой **"сброс настроек сети"**